# Kartik DepDrop at update form not working in Yii2

Tags: yii2

For example, we have an update form with the fields

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->dropDownList($data,
                ['prompt' => 'Select Company Name..', 'id' => 'cat-id']
            ) ?>

    <?php 
        echo $form->field($model, 'employee_name')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
            'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id'],
            'pluginOptions'=>[
                'initialize' => true,
                'depends'=>['cat-id'],
                'placeholder'=>'Select...',
                'url'=>yii\helpers\Url::to(['claim/subcat'])
            ]
        ]);
    ?>
```

A value of depended dropdown is not set when the first dropdown has a value `($cat-id)`. It shows placeholder "Choose a model" instead of list of models for current manufacturer. The same happens, when depended dropdown also have a value `($model->model_id)`. It is not showed. Only placeholder "Choose a model" is showed

Comment: did you tried: 'afterInput' => Html::hiddenInput('id',$data->id),

Comment: Frist, in update you need to pre-populate data in second dropdown based on the first. Second, make sure `claim/subcat` is returning required data. 

Note* I had to composer update when I had same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You must do one of the following for update:

Option 1: Set data property array for dependent dropdown to have a preset dependent list on init.
Option 2: Set pluginOptions['initialize'] property to true for dependent dropdown. This will run the ajax calls on init to generate the dropdown list.